# Tomcat loads and old version of .war

Tags: tomcat

I have a tomcat app that was working without problems for months. But suddely (I dont know why) it started to fail. Why? It loads and old version of this app. I created a new .war, I reinstall tomcat but is still loading the old version.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Dude - Tomcat loads what you give it :)  SUGGESTIONS: 1) See if you've got some CI/CD script (like Jenkins) that's picking up some old version from the environment somwhere.  2) Clean your Tomcat directories - including all tmp directories - and reload manually.

Comment: Hi! The problems is that this happened suddenly. I did not upload anything new. The app was working for months , but suddenly one of the JS change to an oldest JS. And I didnt upload anything new. I check it on eclipse, and this JS have the new function (The same that I uploaded 3 months ago, and was working until yesterday).This is the strange, without upload anything on these three months, the error appeared.

Comment: And also y delete all the tomcat installation, I reinstall it, I create the new war  with eclipse (with the version working), but it show (again) the same error. Could it be a compilation problem from eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat will only run what you give it: it won't resurrect phantom .war files.

Per your comments, the Tomcat is *not* in a production environment - everything's apparently all on your workstation.  So Jenkins (or equivalent) isn't an issue.

SUGGESTION:

1. Create a brand new workspace:

> Eclipse > File > Switch Workspace > Other > "workspace-new"

2. Create a new server:

> Eclipse > Window > Show View > Server > Servers > Define a new Server

- Use your existing Tomcat, but create a new Eclipse instance
- Tomcat instances are per-workspace.

For example, your new instance might be under

```
 %USERPROFILE%\workspace-new\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
```

3. Import your project

> Eclipse > File > Import > Import existing project ...

4. Build and execute

> You should *NOT* see an "old version".

Comment: Hi! Thank u! finally the error was with tomcat and my local server as u said, not from my production server :)